# Complex MySQL Query returning almost all the correct rows

Tags: mysql, query

I've created a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f25a6/2) with my schema and some test data. The calculated columns aren't working for some reason in SQLFiddle, but they come out fine in my MYSQL Workbench. Assume they work correctly.

I've gotten this far with my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.orderid,i.invoiceid,i.subinvoicenumber,stockingorderid AS oistockingorderid,

IF(stockingorderid > 0, 0, po.purchaseorderid) AS purchaseorderid,subponumber,po.paidvia,dropshipfee,i.taxstate,

COALESCE(
    (SELECT mfrname 
        FROM cs_products.tblstockingorders so 
        WHERE so.stockingorderid=oistockingorderid),
    po.mfrname)
AS source,

(i.shipping + i.surcharge + 
    (SELECT SUM(additionalshipping * quantity) AS additionalshipping 
        FROM cs_products.tblorderitems 
        WHERE invoiceid=i.invoiceid)) 
AS shipping,

CAST(IF(o.paymentmethod=2, CONCAT('Check: ', i.checknumber),o.paymentmethod) AS CHAR) AS invoicepaidvia,

COALESCE(
    (SELECT (SUM(cost * quantity) * IF(so.mfrdiscount > 0, 1 - so.mfrdiscount, 1)) AS cost 
        FROM cs_products.tblorderitems oi 
        JOIN cs_products.tblallocations a ON oi.orderitemid=a.orderitemid 
        JOIN cs_products.tblstockingorders so ON a.stockingorderid=so.stockingorderid
        WHERE a.stockingorderid=oistockingorderid),
    (SELECT (SUM(cost * quantity) * IF(po.mfrdiscount > 0, 1 - po.mfrdiscount, 1)) AS cost 
        FROM cs_products.tblorderitems 
        WHERE purchaseorderid=po.purchaseorderid)) 
    AS grosscost,

(SELECT SUM(price * quantity)
    FROM cs_products.tblorderitems 
    WHERE invoiceid=i.invoiceid) 
AS grossprice

FROM cs_products.tblorders o 
    JOIN cs_products.tblinvoices i ON o.orderid=i.orderid
    #ordertype of 0 means the order came from the website
    LEFT JOIN cs_products.tblpurchaseorders po ON o.orderid=po.orderid AND IF(o.ordertype<>0, subinvoicenumber=subponumber, subinvoicenumber=0 AND subponumber>=0)
    LEFT JOIN cs_products.tblallocations a ON a.orderid=o.orderid
```

This gets me 95% of the way there. As you can see, for `OrderId` 1287, it shows two records with `stockingorderid`s and none with a `purchaseorderid` even though a purchase order has been attributed to 1287. What I'm expecting to see for the missing row is something like:

```
1287|276|0|NULL|194|0||0|0|'Quality Fabricators'|357.53|0|781.43|11917.70
```

Again, don't worry about the calculated columns, I just want the record to appear. I feel like I'm missing the smallest thing, but I don't know what it is.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to see three records (2 w/ stockingorderid and 1 w/ purchaseorderid) or one with purchaseorderid only?

Comment: @dezso - Three records, 2 w/stockingorderid + no purchaseorderid and 1 w/purchaseorderid + no stockingorderid

Comment: An order can have of multiples of both (PO and SO) linked to one Invoice, or many invoices that have only one PO or SO each

Comment: Are PO and SO mutually exclusive in the desired result set?

Comment: @dezso yes, that is correct.

Comment: My tip is to use a UNION of SO and PO rows.

Comment: @dezso could you please put that somewhere in an answer that I can try out?

Comment: What exactly about the calculated columns isn't working in the SQL Fiddle link? The fact that they are showing "(null)"?

Comment: @JakeFeasel yeah, i don't know why they're showing null. maybe a bug in sqlfiddle? i don't know, they work in my mysql workbench tool.

Comment: I see that your tblorderitems table only has references to invoiceid=275, but your tblinvoices table (which you are attempting to join) has no reference to that id.  This is why you are getting (null) values for your grossprice subselect. I haven't looked at the other subselects too closely, but I suspect a similar issue.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug in SQL Fiddle (btw - sql fiddle is my site).  The site is structured in such a way that would make such a bug very unlikely.

Comment: @JakeFeasel holy crap you're right. it looks like i'm using old orderitem data! ugh. fortunately orderitems aren't too terribly important for what i need from this question. kudos on sqlfiddle! i'd never heard of it before i started trying to figure this issue out. it's really great!

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
o.orderid,
i.invoiceid,
i.subinvoicenumber,
NULL AS oistockingorderid,
po.purchaseorderid,
subponumber,
po.paidvia,
dropshipfee,
i.taxstate
FROM tblorders o 
    JOIN tblinvoices i ON o.orderid=i.orderid
    #ordertype of 0 means the order came from the website
    JOIN tblpurchaseorders po 
      ON o.orderid=po.orderid 
      AND IF(o.ordertype<>0, subinvoicenumber=subponumber, subinvoicenumber=0 AND subponumber>=0)
    LEFT JOIN tblallocations a ON a.orderid=o.orderid

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT 
o.orderid,
i.invoiceid,
i.subinvoicenumber,
stockingorderid AS oistockingorderid,
NULL AS purchaseorderid,
subponumber,
po.paidvia,
dropshipfee,
i.taxstate
FROM tblorders o 
    JOIN tblinvoices i ON o.orderid=i.orderid
    #ordertype of 0 means the order came from the website
    LEFT JOIN tblpurchaseorders po 
      ON o.orderid=po.orderid 
      AND IF(o.ordertype<>0, subinvoicenumber=subponumber, subinvoicenumber=0 AND subponumber>=0)
    LEFT JOIN tblallocations a ON a.orderid=o.orderid
```

The second `SELECT` is just the same as your original.
In the calculated fields you can omit the `COALESCE` from `grosscost`, and use the two halves separately (according to the non-NULL ID).

Comment: i dropped this in my fiddle and got some strange results... are you able to put this in a fiddle?

Comment: @Jason here you are: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f25a6/86
what does strange mean?  Probably I mistook your idea...

Comment: @Jason - Is there any advance on this?

Comment: yes, quite a bit, actually. i [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695591/complex-mysql-query-i-am-so-close-i-can-smell-it) on StackOverflow and got some great help there. thank you for your answer, though!

Comment: @Jason -  could you then link here that answer as an answer and accept it?  Just to keep things clean...